# Jackson YAML reader not parsing yaml file properly

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I'm trying to parse a YAML file with Jackson. Please find the relevant files below.

Yaml file:

```
params:
 - param-one : abcd
 - param-two : abcd
 - param-three : abcd
 - param-four : abcd
```

Model:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "params"
})
@Data
public class ParamsMain {

    @JsonProperty("params")
    private List<Params> params = null;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
            "param-one",
            "param-two",
            "param-three",
            "param-four"
    })
    @Data
    public static class Params {

        @JsonProperty("param-one")
        private String paramOne;

        @JsonProperty("param-two")
        private String paramTwo;

        @JsonProperty("param-three")
        private String paramThree;

        @JsonProperty("param-four")
        private String paramFour;
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the yaml contents as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
ParamsMain paramsMain = objectMapper.readValue(<PATH_OF_YAML_FILE>, ParamsMain.class);
```

But when I try to print the parsed data, this is what I get:

```
[{
    param-one: abcd
    param-two: null
    param-three: null
    param-four: null
},
{
    param-one: null
    param-two: abcd
    param-three: null
    param-four: null
},
{
    param-one: null
    param-two: null
    param-three: abcd
    param-four: null
},
{
    param-one: null
    param-two: null
    param-three: null
    param-four: abcd
}]
```

How can I make it read such that I get the following output, instead of the array I am receiving?

```
param-one: abcd
param-two: abcd
param-three: abcd
param-four: abcd
```

Comment: Please add the code you use for output. The output is not even valid YAML so you seem to not use a YAML library for output. Obviously if you do not transform the input structure to the desired output structure, you will not get the desired output. Is using jackson required? It would be far easier to solve this with SnakeYAML's low-level API.

Comment: Code to print the object:
```System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(paramsMain,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the right way to store the values. I had to change the POJO to the following:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParamsMain {

    @JsonProperty("params")
    private Map<String, String>[] params;

}
```

This helped me store the data in the following format:

```
{{param-one=abcd},{param-two=abcd},{param-three=abcd},{param-four=abcd}}
```

I used the following code to print what is being parsed:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
ParamsMain paramsMain = objectMapper.readValue(<PATH_OF_YAML_FILE>, ParamsMain.class);


//code to print
System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(paramsMain,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
```